# How to do a reduction with numpy.nditer in the first axis

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand how to work with nditer to do a
reduction, in my case converting a 3d array into a 2d array.

I followed the help here
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html and
managed to create a function that applies reduction over the last axis
of the input. With this function

```
def nditer_sum(data, red_axes):
    it = numpy.nditer([data, None],
            flags=['reduce_ok', 'external_loop'],
            op_flags=[['readonly'], ['readwrite', 'allocate']],
            op_axes=[None, red_axes])
    it.operands[1][...] = 0

    for x, y in it:
        y[...] = x.sum()

    return it.operands[1]
```

I can get something equivalent to data.sum(axis=2)

```
>>> data = numpy.arange(2*3*4).reshape((2,3,4))
>>> nditer_sum(data, [0, 1, -1])
[[ 6 22 38]
[54 70 86]]
>>> data.sum(axis=2)
[[ 6 22 38]
[54 70 86]]
```

So to get something equivalent to data.sum(axis=0) I though that it
was enough to change  the argument red_axes to [-1, 0,1]
But the result is quite different.

```
>>> data = numpy.arange(2*3*4).reshape((2,3,4))
>>> data.sum(axis=0)
[[12 14 16 18]
 [20 22 24 26]
 [28 30 32 34]]
>>> nditer_sum(data, [-1, 0, 1])
[[210 210 210 210]
 [210 210 210 210] 
 [210 210 210 210]]
```

In the for loop inside nditer_sum (for x,y in it:), the iterator is
looping 2 times and giving an array of length 12 each time, instead of
looping 12 times and giving an array of length 2 each time. I have
read the numpy documentation several times and googled about this to
no avail. I'm using numpy 1.6 and python 2.7

Comment: -1 in op_axes is documented as "new axis", is this what you are trying to do?
Also documentation feeds [[size x], [size y], [size z]] into op_axes, while you push [None, [size 3]], is that intended?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) says "an operand is a mapping from the dimensions of the iterator to the dimensions of the operand"... whatever that means. In the current example I have copied the code in the [iterating over arrays tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.nditer.html#reduction-iteration), that works, but only with the last axis. In the example, the 3d array has op_axes None (which seems equivalent to [-1, -1, -1]) and the 2d axis has [0, 1, -1]

Comment: I though that changing [0,1,-1] to [-1, 0, 1] would do the reduction on the first axis, but it doesn't work. My question is how to do the reduction on an arbitrary axis.

Comment: Send this very question to developers and get back here? I'd like to know too.

Answer (score 1):

The `axis=0` case works correctly if the `nditer` order is changed to `F`.  Now there are 12 steps with arrays of size (2,) as you wanted.

```
it = np.nditer([data, None],
        flags=['reduce_ok', 'external_loop'],
        op_flags=[['readonly'], ['readwrite', 'allocate']],
        order='F',     # ADDED to loop starting with the last dimension
        op_axes=[None, red_axes])
```

But there isn't a solution like this for middle `axis=1` case.

---

Another approach to iterating on selected dimensions is to construct a 'multi_index' iterator on a reduced dimensional array.  I discovered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097271/901925 that  `np.ndindex` uses this trick to perform a 'shallow iteration'.

For the `axis=0` case, this function works:

```
def sum_1st(data):
    y = np.zeros(data.shape[1:], data.dtype)
    it = np.nditer(y, flags=['multi_index'])
    while not it.finished:
        xindex = tuple([slice(None)]+list(it.multi_index))
        y[it.multi_index] = data[xindex].sum()
        it.iternext()
    return y
```

Or generalized to any axis:

```
def sum_any(data, axis=0):
    yshape = list(data.shape)
    del yshape[axis]
    y = np.zeros(yshape, data.dtype)
    it = np.nditer(y, flags=['multi_index'])
    while not it.finished:
        xindex = list(it.multi_index)
        xindex.insert(axis, slice(None))
        y[it.multi_index] = data[xindex].sum()
        it.iternext()
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line `y[...] = x.sum()` to `y[...] += x` fixes it (as in the example [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.nditer.html#reduction-iteration)).

Comment: But that's not what I want to do. I'm using a more complex function that does a bunch of operations on x. Imagine that instead of the sum is "the sum after clipping the 10% lower and higher of x"

Comment: I'm just saying that the fix makes the behaviour consistent with numpy.sum with any axis specified, which seemed to be the question... Maybe you should add details to the question.