# shallow iteration with nditer

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I've got such an array:

```
>>>y = np.random.randint(0, 255, (2,2,3))
>>>array([[[242, 14, 211],
           [198,  7,   0]],

          [[235,  60,  81],
           [164,  64, 236]]])
```

And I have to iterate over each **triplet** element (unfortunately vectorization won't help me here...). So I tried:

```
for i, j in np.nditer(y):
print y[i, j],
```

hoping I'd get such an output:

`[242, 14, 211], [198, 7, 0], [235, 60, 81], [164, 64, 236]`, but no luck!

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-21-a336ef837a8a>", line 1, in <module>
    for i, j in np.nditer(y):    print y[i,j]

TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

I'm quite sure I'm making a very obvious error... can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to flatten this down a level.  You can use the `chain` operator from itertools.

```
from itertools import chain    


y = np.random.randint(0, 255, (2,2,3)
b = chain.from_iterable(y) # where b is a generator
```

**list(b) output**

```
[array([ 51, 119,  84]),
 array([ 50, 110, 193]),
 array([165, 157,  52]),
 array([239, 119,  83])]
```

Answer (score 4):

Or reshape `y`

```
for i in y.reshape(-1,3):
    print i
```

A double iteration also works:

```
for x in y:
    for z in x:
        print z
```

Plain `nditer` iterates over each element of `y`  (`nditer` does not give you the indices):

```
for i in np.nditer(y):
    print i   
    # wrong y[i]
```

You'll need to dig more into the flags and documentation for `nditer` to iterate over 2 of its dimensions.  While `nditer` gives access to the underlying iteration mechanism, you don't usually need to use it - unless you are doing something unusual, or trying to speed up code with `cython`.

---

Here's an example of getting 2 values from iteration on an `nditer` object.  There is one value for each array in the `op` list.  Both `x` and `z` are `()` shape arrays.

```
for x,z in np.nditer([y,y]):
    print x,z
```

There's more on the use of `nditer` at
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

---

This doc page has an example using `external_loop` that dishes out the array in subarrays, rather than individually.  I can accomplish the same with the 3d `y` by reordering its axes:

```
y3=y.swapaxes(2,0).copy(order='C')
for i in np.nditer(y3,order='F',flags=['external_loop']):
    print i,

[242  14 211] [198   7   0] [235  60  81] [164  64 236]
```

So we can use `nditer` to do this shallow iteration, but is it worth it?

---

In [Iterating over first d axes of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249380), I stumbled upon `ndindex`:

```
for i in np.ndindex(y.shape[:2]):
    print y[i],
# [242  14 211] [198   7   0] [235  60  81] [164  64 236]
```

`ndindex` uses `nditer`.  The trick to generating shallow iteration is to use a subarray using just the dimensions you want to iterate over.

```
class ndindex(object):
    def __init__(self, *shape):
        ...
        x = as_strided(_nx.zeros(1), shape=shape, strides=_nx.zeros_like(shape))
        self._it = _nx.nditer(x, flags=['multi_index', 'zerosize_ok'], order='C')
    def __next__(self):
        next(self._it)
        return self._it.multi_index
```

Or stripping out the essential parts of `ndindex` I get:

```
xx = np.zeros(y.shape[:2])
it = np.nditer(xx,flags=['multi_index'])                               
while not it.finished:
    print y[it.multi_index],
    it.iternext()
# [242  14 211] [198   7   0] [235  60  81] [164  64 236]
```

Comment: Thanks for the 2 elements at a time trick! :-) It still iterates on each element of the array, though... I'll see if I can tweak that into something that could serve my needs.

Comment: That '2 elements at a time' trick is like the Python `zip`, a way of stepping through 2 or more arrays in unison, so you can combine them, e.g. `x+z`.  What you want is the elements in N item chunks from just one array.  It may be possible to trick `nditer` into doing that, but that is not what it is designed for.

Comment: found a solution using `nditer` - by swapping axes and playing with the order.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Indeed, it seems that using `nditer` in this case is more trouble than it is worth. However I'll try to do a `timeit` when I get home, just to see what I get.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249380 I stumbled upon `np.ndindex`, which uses `nditer`.  It accomplishes a 'shallow iteration' by creating a `zeros` array over selected dimensions.