# Iterating over first d axes of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm given an array with an arbitrary number of axes, and I want to iterate over, say the first 'd' of them. How do I do this?

Initially I thought I would make an array containing all the indices I want to loop through, using

```
i = np.indices(a.shape[:d])
indices = np.transpose(np.asarray([x.flatten() for x in i]))
for idx in indices:
    a[idx]
```

But apparently I cannot index an array like that, i.e. using another array containing the index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ndindex`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html):

```
d = 2
a = np.random.random((2,3,4))
for i in np.ndindex(a.shape[:d]):
    print i, a[i]
```

Output:

```
(0, 0) [ 0.72730488  0.2349532   0.36569509  0.31244037]
(0, 1) [ 0.41738425  0.95999499  0.63935274  0.9403284 ]
(0, 2) [ 0.90690468  0.03741634  0.33483221  0.61093582]
(1, 0) [ 0.06716122  0.52632369  0.34441657  0.80678942]
(1, 1) [ 0.8612884   0.22792671  0.15628046  0.63269415]
(1, 2) [ 0.17770685  0.47955698  0.69038541  0.04838387]
```

Comment: Very close, I'm pretty sure you want `ndindex`!

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple recursive function:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0,10,size=4).reshape((1,1,1,1,2,2))

def recursiveIter(d, level=0):
    print level
    if level <= 2:
        for item in d:
            recursiveIter(item, level+1)
    else:
        print d

recursiveIter(data)
```

outputs:

```
0
1
2
3
[[[2 5]
  [6 0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reshape `a` to compress the 1st `d` dimensions into one:

```
for x in a.reshape(-1,*a.shape[d:]):
    print x
```

or

```
aa=a.reshape(-1,*a.shape[d:])
for i in range(aa.shape[0]):
    print aa[i]
```

We really need to know more about what you need to do with `a[i]`.

---

`shx2` uses `np.ndenumerate`.  The doc for that function mentions `ndindex`.  That could be used as:

```
for i in np.ndindex(a.shape[:d]):
    print i
    print a[i]
```

Where `i` is a tuple.  It's instructive to look at the Python code for these functions.  `ndindex` for example uses `nditer`.