# How to specify depth of iterator in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator

I have a multidimensional array in numpy (e.g. 4D) and I want to specify the depth of the numpy iterator and I am not sure how to do this please?

For example, let's say I have a 4D numpy array, and I want to get elements form the iterator only for the 2D level (so then each item would be also 2D). Is there a way to specify such depth in the iterator please?

I do really want to use an iterator instead of a double loop, and I want to use numpy instead of other tools such as dictionaries and pandas.

As such, I would like this code to output [1 2]'s instead of 1,2...

```
x = np.array(\
(\
\
(\
(np.array([1,2]), np.array([1,2])),\
(np.array([1,2]), np.array([1,2]))\
),\
\
(\
(np.array([1,2]), np.array([1,2])),\
(np.array([1,2]), np.array([1,2]))\
)\
\
)
, dtype = np.ndarray)

for i in np.nditer(x, flags = ["refs_ok"]):
     print i
```

Gives me:

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

Instead of:

```
[1 2]
[1 2]
[1 2]
[1 2]
[1 2]
[1 2]
[1 2]
[1 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.ndindex` does a nice job of iterating over specified dimensions.

Your `x` is a 4d `object` array `dtype=ndarray` becomes `dtype=object`.  Though with tuples all the same size the elements are really just scalars, not arrays.

```
In [385]: x
Out[385]: 
array([[[[1, 2],
         [1, 2]],

        [[1, 2],
         [1, 2]]],


       [[[1, 2],
         [1, 2]],

        [[1, 2],
         [1, 2]]]], dtype=object)

In [386]: x.shape
Out[386]: (2, 2, 2, 2)
```

In any case, `np.ndindex` generates the indices that will iterate over an array of a given shape.

```
In [387]: for i,j in np.ndindex(x.shape[:2]):
    print(i,j)       
    print(x[i,j])
   .....:     
0 0
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]
0 1
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]
1 0
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]
1 1
[[1 2]
 [1 2]]
```

The key pieces of `ndindex` are `as_strided` used to generate a dummy matrix of the right size, and `nditer` with `multi_index` mode to generate the indexes.

earlier examples of this use:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28727290/901925

[Iterating over first d axes of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249380/iterating-over-first-d-axes-of-numpy-array/)

More on trying to create an array of arrays (not just a higher dimensional array of numbers):

[Convert a numpy array to an array of numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283816/convert-a-numpy-array-to-an-array-of-numpy-arrays)

To make an `x` that really is an array of arrays, you need to do something like:

```
In [397]: x=np.zeros((2,2,2),dtype=object)
In [398]: for ijk in np.ndindex(x.shape):
             x[ijk] = np.array([1,2])


In [399]: x
Out[399]: 
array([[[array([1, 2]), array([1, 2])],
        [array([1, 2]), array([1, 2])]],

       [[array([1, 2]), array([1, 2])],
        [array([1, 2]), array([1, 2])]]], dtype=object)
```

---

Another option is to reshape the initial dimensions, so you can do a flat iteration on those:

```
for i in x.reshape(-1,2):
    print(i)
```

`nditer` (and by extension `ndindex`) is described as being efficient, but that applies more to its `C/cython` use.  In pure Python code the iteration mechanism doesn't matter as much.  Actions in the body of the iteration usually take more time.  `nditer` is also best when you need coordinate iteration over multiple array, as in `out[...] = a[...] * b[...]`.  It doesn't off much special with just iterating over one array.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.nditer.html

is a good `nditer` tutorial.  The cython part at the end is best part.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to try this. You are awesome! Quick clarification: is there any performance difference between ndindex and nditer please?

Comment: I expanded on the efficieny issue.

Comment: thank you very much! I am new to numpy. May I ask how you became so good with the details for numpy so I can learn from you please? Is there a good resource (book, class, etc) you'd recommend please? Sorry if I bother you, that will be my last question. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @dvvvvvvvvvvvvvvaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa peruse a resource ([example](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook)) which covers numpy in some depth, find the features you like most about numpy, then practice those (code katas?).