# Iterate over columns of a NumPy array and elements of another one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to replicate the behaviour of `zip(a, b)` in order to be able to loop simultaneously along two `NumPy` arrays. In particular, I have two arrays `a` and `b`:

```
a.shape=(n,m)
b.shape=(m,)
```

I would like to get for every loop a column of `a` and an element of `b`.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
for a_column, b_element in np.nditer([a, b]):
    print(a_column)
```

However, I get printed the element `a[0,0]` rather than the column `a[0,:]`, which I want.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `zip` on numpy arrays, because they are iterables.

In your case, you'd need to transpose `a` first, to make it an array of shape `(m,n)`, i.e. an iterable of length `m`:

```
for a_column, b_element in zip(a.T, b):
    ...
```

Comment: This is the most pythonic answer. `np.nditer` is potentially more powerful but a whole lot uglier. For instance, you have to recall the difference between C- and Fortran-ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting my answer in [shallow iteration with nditer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096600/shallow-iteration-with-nditer/25097271#25097271),
`nditer` and `ndindex` can be used to iterate over rows or columns by generating indexes.

```
In [19]: n,m=3,4
In [20]: a=np.arange(n*m).reshape(n,m)
In [21]: b=np.arange(m)

In [22]: it=np.nditer(b)
In [23]: for i in it: print a[:,i],b[i]
[0 4 8] 0
[1 5 9] 1
[ 2  6 10] 2
[ 3  7 11] 3

In [24]: for i in np.ndindex(m):print a[:,i],b[i]
[[0]
 [4]
 [8]] 0
[[1]
 [5]
 [9]] 1
[[ 2]
 [ 6]
 [10]] 2
[[ 3]
 [ 7]
 [11]] 3
In [25]:
```

`ndindex` uses an iterator like: `it = np.nditer(b, flags=['multi_index']`.

For iteration over a single dimension like this, `for i in range(m):` works just as well.

Also from the other thread, here's a trick using `order` to iterate without the indexes:

```
In [28]: for i,j in np.nditer([a,b],order='F',flags=['external_loop']):
    print i,j
[0 4 8] [0 0 0]
[1 5 9] [1 1 1]
[ 2  6 10] [2 2 2]
[ 3  7 11] [3 3 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, because of NumPy's ability to [broadcast arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), it is not necessary to iterate over the columns of an array one-by-one. For example, if `a` has shape `(n,m)` and `b` has shape `(m,)` then you can add `a+b` and `b` will broadcast itself to shape `(n, m)` automatically.

Moreover, your calculation will complete much faster if it can be expressed through operations on the whole array, `a`, rather than through operations on pieces of `a` (such as on columns) using a Python `for-loop`.

Having said that, the easiest way to loop through the columns of `a` is to iterate over the index:

```
for i in np.arange(b.shape[0]):
    a_column, b_element = a[:, i], b[i]
    print(a_column)
```