# Numpy Broadcast indices from shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have 2 array shapes which are broadcastable against eachother.

e.g. (2, 2, 1) and (2, 3)

I want a function that takes those shapes and gives me an iterator returning the indices from these arrays with these shapes that would be broadcast together, and the indices in the resulting output array.

```
iter, output_shape = broadcast_indeces_iterator((2, 2, 1), (2, 3))
assert output_shape == (2, 2, 3)
for in1_ix, in_2_ix, out_ix in iter:
    print (in1_ix, in_2_ix, out_ix)
```

results in output:

```
(0, 0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 0), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)
(1, 0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0, 2)
(1, 1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 1, 2)
```

np.broadcast does something close but wants actual created arrays.

- Note to NumPy people: It would be nice for np.broadcast to have an additional argument allowing you to not iterate, for instance, over the last 2 dimensions.  This would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
x = 10*np.arange(4).reshape((2, 2, 1))
y = 100*np.arange(6).reshape((2, 3))

z = np.nditer([x, y], flags=['multi_index', 'c_index'], order='C')
for a,b in z:
    print(np.unravel_index(z.index % x.size, x.shape)
          , np.unravel_index(z.index % y.size, y.shape)
          , z.multi_index)
```

yields

```
((0, 0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
((0, 1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0, 1))
((1, 0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 0, 2))
((1, 1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1, 0))
((0, 0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1, 1))
((0, 1, 0), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2))
((1, 0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0, 0))
((1, 1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0, 1))
((0, 0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0, 2))
((0, 1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1, 0))
((1, 0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1))
((1, 1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Nice, succinct, but it requires that the arrays be instantiated in order to get the indices.  Real problem for me is that I only want to iterate over the first ndim-2 dimensions of each array.

Comment: Broadcasting arrays with shapes (2, 1) and (1, 2) together gives (0, 0) (0, 0) (0, 0); (0, 1) (1, 0) (0, 1); (0, 0) (0, 0) (1, 0); (0, 1) (1, 0) (1, 1) Two combinations of inputs giving 4 combinations of output is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

What a great question Peter.  Here is your answer:

```
import numpy as np


def get_broadcast_shape(*shapes):
    '''
    Given a set of array shapes, return the shape of the output when arrays of those 
    shapes are broadcast together
    '''
    max_nim = max(len(s) for s in shapes)
    equal_len_shapes = np.array([(1, )*(max_nim-len(s))+s for s in shapes]) 
    max_dim_shapes = np.max(equal_len_shapes, axis = 0)
    assert np.all(np.bitwise_or(equal_len_shapes==1, equal_len_shapes == max_dim_shapes[None, :])), \
        'Shapes %s are not broadcastable together' % (shapes, )
    return tuple(max_dim_shapes)


def get_broadcast_indeces(*shapes):
    '''
    Given a set of shapes of arrays that you could broadcast together, return:
        output_shape: The shape of the resulting output array
        broadcast_shape_iterator: An iterator that returns a len(shapes)+1 tuple
            of the indeces of each input array and their corresponding index in the 
            output array
    '''
    output_shape = get_broadcast_shape(*shapes)
    base_iter = np.ndindex(output_shape)

    def broadcast_shape_iterator():
        for out_ix in base_iter:
            in_ixs = tuple(tuple(0 if s[i] == 1 else ix for i, ix in enumerate(out_ix[-len(s):])) for s in shapes)
            yield in_ixs + (out_ix, )

    return output_shape, broadcast_shape_iterator()


output_shape, ix_iter = get_broadcast_indeces((2, 2, 1), (2, 3))
assert output_shape == (2, 2, 3)
for in1_ix, in_2_ix, out_ix in ix_iter:
    print (in1_ix, in_2_ix, out_ix)
```

returns

```
((0, 0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
((0, 0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0, 1))
((0, 0, 0), (0, 2), (0, 0, 2))
((0, 1, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1, 0))
((0, 1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1, 1))
((0, 1, 0), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2))
((1, 0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0, 0))
((1, 0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0, 1))
((1, 0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0, 2))
((1, 1, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1, 0))
((1, 1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1))
((1, 1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 1, 2))
```

If anyone knows of any numpy builtins that solve this, that would be better though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

```
array1 = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2,1)*10
array2 = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

I, J = np.broadcast_arrays(array1, array2)
print I.shape
K = np.empty(I.shape, dtype=int)
for ijk in np.ndindex(I.shape):
    K[ijk] = I[ijk]+J[ijk]
print K
```

producing

```
(2, 2, 3)  # broadcasted shape

[[[ 0  1  2]
  [13 14 15]]    
 [[20 21 22]
  [33 34 35]]]
```

`I` is `(2,2,3)`, but shares its data with `array1` - it's a broadcasted view, not a copy (look at its `.__array_interface__`).

You can iterate over just 2 dimensions by giving `ndindex` just those shapes.

```
K = np.empty(I.shape, dtype=int)
for i,j in np.ndindex(I.shape[:2]):
    K[i,j,:] = I[i,j,:]+J[i,j,:]
    print K[i,j,:]
```

It can be refined by looking at the code for `broadcast_arrays` and `ndindex` to find the essential pieces.  For example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097271/901925 I call `nditer` directly to generate a `multi_index` (an operation which could be adapted to cython).

```
xx = np.zeros(y.shape[:2])
it = np.nditer(xx,flags=['multi_index'])                               
while not it.finished:
    print y[it.multi_index],
    it.iternext()
# [242  14 211] [198   7   0] [235  60  81] [164  64 236]
```

---

To make 'dummy arrays' that are virtually costless, I could take a clue from `ndindex`, and make array starting with `np.zeros(1)`

```
def make_dummy(shape):
    x = as_strided(np.zeros(1),shape=shape, strides=np.zeros_like(shape))
    return x
array1 = make_dummy((2,2,1))
array2 = make_dummy((2,3))
```

I could dig into `np.broadcast_arrays` to find out how it combines the shapes from the 2 input arrays to come up with the shape for `I`.

---

There's a difference between your desired solution and mine that I've glossed over.

```
(0, 0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0, 1)
...
(1, 1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 1, 2)
```

expects a different iterator tuple for each array, one that ranges over `(2,2,1)`, another than ranges over `(2,3)`, etc.

My approach, which I believe is that used by `numpy` c code (at least those parts based on `nditer`), generates one iterator over `(2,2,3)`, and massages the arrays, via `as_strided` to accept that larger range.  It is easier to implement a general broadcasting mechanism this way.  It separates the broadcasting complexity from the calculation core.

Here's a good intro to `nditer`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

Comment: Good.  But, the solution depends on the creation of dummy arrays (in1_ix, ind2_ix), even though it only needs their shape information to come up with the indices.

Comment: I added information on how to make a dummy array that is just a view on `np.zeros(1)`.