# Python 2.7: looping over 1D fibers in a multidimensional Numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array, iteration

I am looking for a way to loop over `1D` fibers (row, column, and multi-dimensional equivalents) along any dimension in a 3+-dimensional array.

In a `2D` array this is fairly trivial since the fibers are rows and columns, so just saying `for row in A` gets the job done. But for `3D` arrays for example, this expression iterates over `2D` slices, not `1D` fibers.

A working solution is the one below:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
func = np.sum
for fiber_index in np.ndindex(A.shape[:-1]):
    print func(A[fiber_index])
```

However, I am wondering whether there is something that is:

1. More idiomatic
2. Faster

Hope you can help!

Comment: Is `np.sum` just an example? Your options are very different if your `func` is a built-in numpy ufunc, or you need to use a generic Python function.

Comment: Does `func` take a scalar, 1d vector or multi-dim array?  `ndindex` uses the most basic numpy iterator, `nditer`.  More at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25097271/901925

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html)

```
In [10]: def my_func(x):
   ...:     return x**2 + x

In [11]: np.apply_along_axis(my_func, 2, A)
Out[11]: 
array([[[  0,   2,   6],
        [ 12,  20,  30],
        [ 42,  56,  72]],

       [[ 90, 110, 132],
        [156, 182, 210],
        [240, 272, 306]],

       [[342, 380, 420],
        [462, 506, 552],
        [600, 650, 702]]])
```

Although many NumPy functions (including `sum`) have their own `axis` argument to specify which axis to use:

```
In [12]: np.sum(A, axis=2)
Out[12]: 
array([[ 3, 12, 21],
       [30, 39, 48],
       [57, 66, 75]])
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I was actually already using it, but because of a bug I thought I had misunderstood its effect, so that is partly what sent me searching for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy` provides a number of different ways of looping over 1 or more dimensions.

Your example:

```
func = np.sum
for fiber_index in np.ndindex(A.shape[:-1]):
    print func(fiber_index)
    print A[fiber_index]
```

produces something like:

```
(0, 0)
[0 1 2]
(0, 1)
[3 4 5]
(0, 2)
[6 7 8]
...
```

generates all index combinations over the 1st 2 dim, giving your function the 1D fiber on the last.

Look at the code for `ndindex`.  It's instructive.  I tried to extract it's essence in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097271/901925.

It uses `as_strided` to generate a dummy matrix over which an `nditer` iterate.  It uses the 'multi_index' mode to generate an index set, rather than elements of that dummy.  The iteration itself is done with a `__next__` method.  This is the same style of indexing that is currently used in `numpy` compiled code.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.nditer.html
`Iterating Over Arrays` has good explanation, including an example of doing so in `cython`.

Many functions, among them `sum`, `max`, `product`, let you specify which axis (axes) you want to iterate over.  Your example, with `sum`, can be written as:

```
np.sum(A, axis=-1)
np.sum(A, axis=(1,2))   # sum over 2 axes
```

An equivalent is

```
np.add.reduce(A, axis=-1)
```

`np.add` is a `ufunc`, and `reduce` specifies an iteration mode.  There are many other `ufunc`, and other iteration modes - `accumulate`, `reduceat`.  You can also define your own `ufunc`.

`xnx` suggests

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.sum, 2, A)
```

It's worth digging through `apply_along_axis` to see how it steps through the dimensions of `A`.  In your example, it steps over all possible `i`,`j` in a `while` loop, calculating:

```
outarr[(i,j)] = np.sum(A[(i, j, slice(None))])
```

Including `slice` objects in the indexing tuple is a nice trick.  Note that it edits a list, and then converts it to a tuple for indexing.  That's because tuples are immutable.

---

Your iteration can applied along any axis by rolling that axis to the end.  This is a 'cheap' operation since it just changes the strides.

```
def with_ndindex(A, func, ax=-1):
    # apply func along axis ax
    A = np.rollaxis(A, ax, A.ndim) # roll ax to end (changes strides)
    shape = A.shape[:-1]
    B = np.empty(shape,dtype=A.dtype)
    for ii in np.ndindex(shape):
        B[ii] = func(A[ii])
    return B
```

I did some timings on 3x3x3, 10x10x10 and 100x100x100 `A` arrays.  This `np.ndindex` approach is consistently a third faster than the `apply_along_axis` approach.  Direct use of `np.sum(A, -1)` is much faster.

So if `func` is limited to operating on a 1D fiber (unlike `sum`), then the `ndindex` approach is a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! A lot of extra information I am going to enjoy digging in to.