# Custom nditer Behavior

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working with some image data of shape (x,y,3). Is a way to use a numpy construct like `nditer` to iterate over the (r,g,b) tuples corresponding to pixels? Out of the box, `nditer` iterates over the scalar values, but many numpy functions have something like a `axis=` argument to change behavoirs like this.

Answer (score 0):

Check `np.ndindex`. It's doc may be enough to get you started.  Better yet, read its code.

I have answered similar questions by essentially reverse enginerring `ndindex`.  If there isn't a link in the `Related` sidebar, I'll do a quick search.

[shallow iteration with nditer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096600/shallow-iteration-with-nditer?rq=1)